# Not able to create a new project on Google developer cosole

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-api

I'm trying to create a new project on google developer console which repeatedly is throwing a error "Bad request"

[image]

Comment: You probably can't create projects with "google" in the name. Try using non-trademarked names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved. After logging in, I first deleted all the existing projects and then immediately after that I created a project which was throwing an error. Basically, you have to create new project you have to wait for sometime if you have deleted the project.